# How type parameters are passed to next method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, fluent, method-chaining

Given the following method-chain:

```
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Student>()
        .HasOne<StudentAddress>(s => s.Address)
        .WithOne(ad => ad.Student);
```

How does `HasOne` know about the `Student` type (shown in lambda argument) provided by its previous method `Entity<Student>`?

Seems to me as if `Entity<Student>` somehow passes its designated type parameter `Student` to the next method via chaining (return  value of `Entity<Student>` being the base object for next method `HasOne`).

Comment: "Seems to me as if Entity<Student> somehow passes its designated type parameter Student to the next method via chaining (return value of Entity<Student> being the base object for next method HasOne)." That's exactly what happens.

Comment: But how exactly, what is the syntax or part of the syntax that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are calling [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_Entity__1):

```
public virtual EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> Entity<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
```

Look closely at the signature. The method takes a generic parameter called `TEntity`, and returns a `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`, allowing you to chain any calls that can be called on `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>` at the end of a call to `Entity<TEntity>()` call.

In your case, you called `Entity<Student>()`, so the signature dictates that the result must be a `EntityTypeBuilder<Student>`. Then, you were able to call [`EntityTypeBuilder<Student>.HasOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasone?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_1_HasOne__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___):

```
public virtual ReferenceNavigationBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity> HasOne<TRelatedEntity> (Expression<Func<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>> navigationExpression = null) where TRelatedEntity : class;
```

Look at what `HasOne` accepts - `Expression<Func<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>>`. Because you are calling `EntityTypeBuilder<Student>.HasOne`, `TEntity` is `Student`. The compiler sees your lambda expression and infers that `s` must be `Student`, because that's the only way that the lambda expression could be converted to `Expression<Func<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>>`.

Also note that `HasOne` returns a `ReferenceNavigationBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>`, which allows you to chain other calls, and that now you have passed two pieces of type information `TEntity` and `TRelatedEntity`.

In fact, you don't need to specify the generic parameter for `HasOne`, the compiler can infer those as well:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Student>()
    .HasOne(s => s.Address)
    .WithOne(ad => ad.Student);
```

Comment: How does it infer `TRelatedEntity`?

Comment: @chakmeshma it knows that `s.Address` is `StudentAddress`.